# query regarding Spark and Hive SQL Optimizer

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have a confusion regarding Spark catalyst SQL optimizer (it will be useful if someone can also throw some light on Hive's query optimizer). Following is a query with two subqueries q1, and q2. If you notice closely, except for, value of the predicate `is.true` everything else is the same in both the subqueries. My question is, if the Spark or Hive query optimizer will be able to identify this redundancy/similarity and optimize the query to do all the shuffling only once.

```
select q1.count1, q2.count2 from
(select count(q_id) as count1 from 
(select u.tbl, q_id, max(m.is_true) as is_true from
(select tbl, schema, q_id from umap where a_id=1234) u 
join 
(select distinct schema, table_name, is_true from metadata where id=1234) m 
on u.schema = m.schema and u.tbl = m.table_name 
group by tbl,q_id) p where p.is_true=1) q1,

(select count(q_id) as count2 from 
(select u.tbl, q_id, max(m.is_true) as is_true from
(select tbl, schema, q_id from umap where a_id=1234) u 
join 
(select distinct schema, table_name, is_true from metadata where id=1234) m 
on u.schema = m.schema and u.tbl = m.table_name 
group by tbl,q_id) p where p.is_true=0) q2
```

Thanks

Comment: This is a really bad written query.

Comment: hi @DuduMarkovitz, can you suggest me how to make this query more efficient.

Comment: Hi , Please add a data sample including required results